# How to correctly account for transaction costs when swapping from one ERC-20 token to another using for example the Kyber network?

Tags: gas-limit, gas-estimate, swaps

If I for example have 5 KNC (an ERC-20 token) and would like to swap them for *x* amount of DAI (another ERC-20), this would on the Kyber network, as far as I understand, be achieved via two conversions: first KNC to ETH followed by ETH to DAI.

Given the ask and bid rates of the involved pairs, the resulting DAI quantity obtained from 5 KNC would then, without any transaction fees, be:

DAI<sub>QTY</sub> = (KNC<sub>QTY</sub> × ETH_KNC<sub>Bid rate</sub>) × (1 / ETH_DAI<sub>Ask rate</sub>)

My question is: how do I modify this expression to correctly account for transaction fees?

Are there two separate transaction fees since I have two swaps? The Kyber API can return the expected gas limit needed for a token2token swap (expressed in ETH), but I’m not sure how to apply it when calculating the expected token amount received given an input token amount.

Comment: You have two separate gas fees (paid in ether deducted from your account ether balance). And you have two separate token fees (paid in either source token or target token deducted from your account).

Comment: The "either source token or target token" part depends on Kyber's implementation. These "tokens" may well be ether itself (represented via a logical ETH token I suppose, for example, WETH). This too, depends on Kyber's implementation decision.

Comment: @goodvibration Oh, so there are a total of 4 fees? That sounds complicated. By “paid in ether deducted from your account ether balance”, are you saying that I cannot even make a token2token swap without also having an ETH balance on the address? I was under the impression that Kyber token2token swaps could be realized without altering the ETH balance.

Comment: You cannot make ANY transaction without also having an ether balance on the account that you are sending the transaction from.